# Cannot recreate innodb database after I deleted it from data because :"Tables already exist"

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I know this has similarities with the shroedingers table problem, but it reaches father than that.

I'm using Mysql Server 5.6 with innodb and file per table enabled.

I recently deleted a few databases from the mysql/server/data folder. They where too big and the server went away when I tried to do it with a drop, so I thought that was the cleanest option.

Now I'm trying to recreate the database from a sql-file and I get the messages "table xy already exists" for all the tables in the database, even though I checked the data folder and it was empty before I started the file. As the file is running, the idb files for the databases are created, not the frm though, so I end up with tablespaces that I cannot fill.

Obviously the server still has some information about the deleted databases saved somewhere that I need to get rid of, I just have no idea where to look for it.

Here an excerpt from the scheme file

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.13, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.13-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,     FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
--
-- Table structure for table `articles`
--

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `articlesID` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`articlesID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;enter code here
```

Comment: Can you login to the mysql server on the command line and try the following `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "datadir";` and `show tables;`?

Run  `show tables;` only after switching to the db you are interested in by running `use <db_name>;`
Also, have you actually dropped the tables by using `drop`, or just deleted files from some directory?

Comment: Put in schema file CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `databasename` ;
USE `databasename`; .... I think your database is not default database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system structures in the file `ibdata1` contain information about all InnoDB tables.  It did not get cleaned up when you deleted the database directories.

Plan A:  (This has some risk.)  Dump the rest of your tables using mysqldump (or some other took); stop mysqld; delete `ibdata1`; restart mysqld; reload the dump.

Plan B:  (Low risk.)  Abandon those database names.

Plan C:  (Serious risk.)  Hire an expert (not me) to fiddle with `ibdata1`.  (Suggestions: Percona, MariaDB, Oracle.)

Plan D:  (unknown risk.)  Do some web searches.  Someone has probably conquered this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. Deleting ibdata1 worked. Luckily where was nothing on there I couldn't recreate from backups anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**It's a bad practice to delete file/s directly inside the `data` folder.** Keep in mind that file/s has logs. Here's my suggestion:

- Undo or Restore from the Recycle Bin the deleted files from the `data` folder
- Make sure you are in the same server where you deleted them (`ib_logfile`, `ibdata`, etc should be there)
- Try to DROP the table again

*Please tell me if these thing works.*